# Bypass DNS lookup and submit URL to proxy

Tags: java, proxy, dns, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I have Java application that uses Apache HttpComponents to make web request. 
I have configured the application to use Proxy Servers using the JVM Property

`java -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3132`

Currently my java application client makes DNS lookup in which it will fail.
I want the Proxy to do the DNS resolution just like how web browsers do in automatic Proxy configuration mode (with .pac files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking here:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java

It seems as though you need to specify a proxy using setProxy() and not global properties.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record this how one can make HttpClient pick up system proxy settings

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
    .setRoutePlanner(
         new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(ProxySelector.getDefault()))
    .build();
```

or this if you want HttpClient fully configured based on system prperties

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createSystem();
```