# Bypass DNS lookup, submit URL to proxy and get IP of host

Tags: java, proxy, dns, ip, ip-address

I need to make a proxy do the DNS resolution for me and give me the IP address of that host. I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935617/bypass-dns-lookup-and-submit-url-to-proxy) with [this snippet](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java), but it doesn't give me IP of the host - or I don't know how.

I saw some solutions with `InetAddress` to get the IP address of a certain host, but haven't found a solution with a proxy yet.

Thank you